# Why am I only getting grayscales / monotones when applying colors in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color-spaces, live-trace, configuration

When I try to change the color after tracing a `JPEG` image in Illustrator and expanding it, it becomes gray. I have tried lots of color changes but the result is always the same.

**Why can't I change the color to anything other than gray, on an image I've traced in Adobe Illustrator?**

**How can I change the traced image's color?**

Answer (score 55):

My guess is that your document colours are set to grayscale. Go to the colour panel, click the little down-arrow in the top right corner, and change there:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes this is my problem also, but I change it and after some time it keeps changing to Grayscale. It's quite annoying!

Comment: To be clear, he's talking about this: http://i.imgur.com/unH1xra.png

Comment: I did an image trace and after expanding, found that each separate object was independently set to Grayscale. Maybe because I used the B&W logo image trace. Really annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Hello there is another question on this website similar to this one with more information in case you were having issues like me:

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/29301/27134

The main key is to "Expand" the image and use the Direct Selection Tool (A).